# Как работать с редактором реестра через python?

Tags: python, реестр

Есть приложение "Параметры" в windows 10. Допустим, мне нужно поставить галочку на игровом режиме в разделе игры. Пришла идея изменить этот параметр через реестр, нашёл какой ключ нужно задействовать, нагуглил winreg для python, но как-то не особо разобрался. Пояснившим вкратце буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь к ключу, его имя, значение и тип, соответственно, подставьте необходимые.

```
import winreg

key_name = 'key_name'
new_val = 'my_val'
key_type = winreg.REG_SZ
path = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'

with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, 0, access=winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key:
    winreg.SetValueEx(key, key_name, 0, key_type, new_val )
```